# Why there isn't a factor of $1/n!$ in the transition probabilities of this reaction?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, stochastic-processes

In Grainder handbook of stochastic methods page 241, a chemical bistable system is given by

[image]

[image]

We want to solve this as a birth-death master equation. My question is about the transition probabilities $t^+(x)$ and $t^-(x)$. My understanding is that it depends on the number of ways $2x$ molecules can react with each other, hence the $x(x-1)$ term. However, why isn't there a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ to avoid double counting. Similarly for the other equation with the term $x(x-1)(x-2)$, should it be divided by $3!$? I don't quite understand why it is neglected here.

Comment: I agree that they should be there. Perhaps those factors have just been absorbed into the constants $k_j$?

Comment: I thought of that. But I don't think that should be the case. If you look at equation 7.1.57 and if A wasn't assumed to be a constant, a rate like k3 would be a production rate of X and at the same time a depletion rate for A. So I thought that absorbing a factor into the reaction rate would mess up the other reaction. In this particular reaction, where only one molecule is needed in the reaction, it wouldn't be a problem. But for another one shouldn't it matter? That's why I can't see absorption of the factor into the rate working as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are counting permutations instead of combinations.  For a permutation, order matters, while for a combination order does not matter.

Specifically for counting n objects k at a time with no duplicates, where order does not matter the number of combinations is $$C(n, k) = {n! \over k!(n-k)!}$$
For counting n objects k at a time with no duplicates, where order does matter the number of permutations is $$P(n, k) = {n! \over (n-k)!}$$